# Om Formatted Text Input Component Cursor Jumping

Tags: validation, reactjs, clojurescript, om

(I'm a little new to OM and React, so apologies if this is documented somewhere that I haven't seen yet.)

I'm trying to make a textbox that validates and formats its input during editing similar to the [autoNumeric](http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/) JS library.

My application is for validating USD currencies (e.g. strings of the form `$1,234.56`). Specifically, the textbox should prevent the user from typing invalid characters (like letters) into the textbox and should format its contents on-the-fly to include the dollar-sign (`$`) and the commas marking the thousands positions. The component should prevent deleting these formatting characters. The formatting is already handled nicely by the JS `toLocaleString` function, but I'm having trouble with the UI and the position of the cursor jumping after input.

I found a relevant [react github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/955) that describes how to prevent the cursor from jumping around after the app-state is updated. The solution from that thread is captured is [a JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/dunutajuqo/edit?js,output), however it is written in javascript using React.

I'm trying to implement a version using ClojureScript and Om, but am having trouble. If I implement the component using only component-local state, and no global app-state, then the cursor does the intended behavior and does not jump around (similar to the autoNumeric library). Ultimately I want to propagate the value to the global app-state. However, when I have the component update the global app-state, then the cursor jumps after each change to the input field.

I've tried many variants including using no local state (only global app-state) and a mix between global and local. Anytime I include global app-state, the cursor jumps.

Here is my current implementation, which does not yet update the global app-state, but does not have a jumping cursor. (Note, I'm using [om-tools](https://github.com/plumatic/om-tools), so the syntax may be a little different from vanilla om.)

```
(defn raw-number [s]
  (let [s (if (empty? s "0" (str s)))]
    (js/parseFloat (str/replace s #"[^-0-9.]" ""))))

(defn format-currency [s]
  (.toLocaleString (raw-number s) "en-US" #js {:style "currency" :currency "USD"}))

(defcomponentk validated-input
  "Component that prevents the cursor from jumping after updates."
  [data owner opts]
  (will-receive-props [_ new-state]
    (when-let [dom-node (om/get-node owner "validated-input")]
      (let [old-length (-> dom-node .-value count)
            old-idx (.-selectionStart dom-node)
            _ (set! (.-value dom-node) new-state)
            new-len (count new-state)
            new-idx (max 0 (-> new-len (- old-length) (+ old-idx)))]
        (om/update! data :cursor-pos new-idx))))

  (did-update [_ _ prev-state]
    (let [new-idx (:cursor-pos data)
          dom-node (om/get-node owner "validated-input")]
      (set! (.-selectionStart dom-node) new-idx)
      (set! (.-selectionEnd dom-node) new-idx)))

  (render [_]
    (dom/input
     (merge
      opts
      {:type "text"
       :ref "validated-input"}))))


(defcomponentk formatted-input
  "Formats the text using the provided formatter before rendering it."
  [data owner [:opts formatter :as opts]]
  (init-state [_]
    {:text (formatter "")})

  (render [_]
    (let [text (om/get-state owner :text)]
      (validated-input
       text ;; << I recognize this to be shady, passing local state down. but it works to prevent the cursor jumping.
       {:opts
        (merge
         opts
         {:value text
          :on-change (fn [e]
                       (let [new-val (formatter (str (.. e -target -value)))]
                         (om/set-state! owner :text new-val)))})}))))
```

Comment: You have to use local state with controlled inputs. Why not just do a write only (no read) to global state?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was getting tripped up because changes to the local state and changes to the global state both triggered a re-render. I ended up using a somewhat hacky workaround using an atom in the local state to avoid retriggering a rerender.

The solution performs well on a desktop, but due to its reliance on the `on-click` or `on-key-down` events, I'm unsure whether it will work well on mobile.

In any case, it suits my needs. Critiques are welcome!

```
(defn save-position! [owner event]
  (let [found-node (om/get-node owner "validated-input")
        idx-atom (om/get-state owner :idx-atom)
        new-idx (if (nil? found-node) @idx-atom (.-selectionStart found-node))]
    (reset! idx-atom new-idx)))

(defcomponentk formatted-input
  "Formats the text using the provided formatter before rendering it."
  [data owner [:opts formatter :as opts]]
  (init-state [_]
    {:idx-atom (atom 0)})

  (did-update [_ prev-props prev-state]
    (let [dom-node (om/get-node owner "validated-input")

          old-text (:text prev-props)
          new-text (:text data)

          old-len (count old-text)
          new-len (count new-text)

          delta-len (- new-len old-len)
          old-idx @(:idx-atom prev-state)

          new-idx (max 0 (+ delta-len old-idx))]
      (set! (.-selectionStart dom-node) new-idx)
      (set! (.-selectionEnd dom-node) new-idx)))

  (render [_]
    (dom/input
     (merge
      opts
      {:value (formatter (str (:text data)))
       :type "text"
       :ref "validated-input"
       :on-click (fn [dom-node] (save-position! owner dom-node))
       :on-key-down (fn [dom-node] (save-position! owner dom-node))
       :on-change (fn [dom-node]
                    (let [new-val (formatter (str (.. dom-node -target -value)))
                          old-idx @(om/get-state owner :idx-atom)
                          found-node (om/get-node owner "validated-input")]
                      (when (not= new-val (.-value found-node))
                        (set! (.-value found-node) new-val)
                        (set! (.-selectionStart found-node) old-idx)
                        (set! (.-selectionEnd found-node) old-idx))
                      (om/update! data :text new-val)))}))))
```